# Is Google's jquery CDN script link missing thew leading "https:" for a reason?

Tags: jquery, cdn, broken-links

I haven't had to grab the link for awhile, but when jquery undefined errors started appearing, I noticed the url in the CDN script link was missing the leading "http:" or "https:". It obviously creates a broken link. I'm wondering if this is intentional or an error on Google's part. Any insight would be great.

Ex: 
`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>`

Should be??: 
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>`

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Comment: Nope, starting with `//` just means 'grab the current protocol and prepend it to the URL'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`//` will give it a realtive protocol. Meaning that if you are accessing `http://example.com` then the cdn link will also use `http://` whereas if you are accessing `https://example.com` then the cdn link will use `https` as well.